# Question about L2 Inner Product and Integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, hilbert-spaces, improper-integrals, inner-products, integral-transforms

Does exists $f\in L_2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that for all $g\in L_2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ which is not identically zero:

$\left[\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)g(x)dx\right]^2+\left[\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}g(x)dx\right]^2>0$ ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can (if the space is over $\mathbb{R}$): Consider $f\in L^2$, then $f=f_1+f_2$ with $f_1\in L_0^2$ and $f_2\in (L_0^2)^{\perp}$ ($L_0^2$ is the space of $L^2$ functions with zero average). By Gram-Schmidt there is $g\in L_0^2$ such that $(f_1,g)_{L^2}=0$. But then $(f,g)_{L^2}=0$. So for this $g$ your LHS is zero.